# Web Console: What is Omniture?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I just came across an interesting LogCat entry:

```
06-28   08:43:25.616    I   Web Console 5075    Omniture: s.t, instance: 1 at :1158337217
06-28   08:43:25.624    I   Web Console 5075    [object Object] at :1158337217
```

What is Omniture (in this context) and where can I learn more about these Web Console messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Omniture is an analytics tool](http://www.omniture.com/), in a sense it's comparable to google analytics. What you're seeing is probably logging of Omniture javascript code on a website you're viewing.

EDIT:

To elaborate. What comes up in the Web Console logs is basically anything that calls console.log() in a webpage that you're viewing.

Comment: This is the most helpful **relevant** piece of information I have seen so far: *"What you're seeing is probably logging of Omniture javascript code on a website you're viewing"*. Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Omniture is a web analytics tool similar to Google Analytics.

`s.t()` is the tracking call of the Omniture tracking library.

Comment: correct your spelling we --> web.  (I can't because it's too minor an edit)

Answer (score -2):

If you have searched for omniture on the net then you would have not put the question. Please do little search before putting the question over `SO`.

Omniture is a `analytical tool` like `google analytics`.

It is a adobe product. Here is the [mobile link](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/mobile-analytics) and [web link](http://www.omniture.com/en/).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question in the **Web Console** context. @GeertWeening is much more helpful.

Comment: you have clearly asked about omniture mentioning it as a console message nevertheless I can understand.